# systemd / service user has not the same rights / permission as same user in a shell

Tags: permissions, systemd, configuration, services, non-root-user

I'm trying to set up the Hashicorp Vault Agent as a systemd service.
I can manually run that agent with the user vault.

Note, perhaps that's important: here's the /etc/passwd for that user :

`vault:x:994:989::/home/vault:/bin/false`

So I need to do `sudo su -s /bin/bash vault` to get a vault session.

With that in mind, I can do the `vault agent -config=<pathToConfig>`and it works.

Now here the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/vault-agent.service` I've set up :

```
[Unit]
Description="HashiCorp Vault - A tool for managing secrets"
Documentation=https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
ConditionFileNotEmpty=/etc/vault.d/vault.hcl

[Service]
User=vault
Group=vault
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=read-only
PrivateTmp=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
SecureBits=keep-caps
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_IPC_LOCK
Capabilities=CAP_IPC_LOCK+ep
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYSLOG CAP_IPC_LOCK
NoNewPrivileges=yes
ExecStart=/bin/vault agent -non-interactive -config=/etc/vault.d/agent-config-prod.hcl
ExecReload=/bin/kill --signal HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGINT
Restart=no
RestartSec=5
TimeoutStopSec=30
StartLimitIntervalSec=60
StartLimitBurst=3
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is a service conf I've found multiple times.

But I always get the same issue: `Error storing PID: could not open pid file: open ./pidfile: permission denied`

I tried to replace the ExecStart= by /bin/whoami, just to be sure, yes, it's indeed vault.
Permission and location of that ./pidfile (default install location):

```
/etc/vault.d/pidfile

drwxr-xr-x. 108 root root  8192 May 15 16:32 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 vault vault     113 May 15 17:43 vault.d
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vault vault   0 May 15 17:48 pidfile #not default permission, but I am desesperate.
```

I am really suspicous about the sudo `su -s /bin/bash vault` command that, perhaps, grants the vault user more privileges. If so, how to incorporate it into my service?

I ran systemctl reload daemon everytime and SELinux is disable.

ps: if someone has a great link about how to set up a systemd for the vault AGENT (not as root), I'll take it.

EDIT :
about the `sudo -s /bin/bash vault`

```
$ sudo -s /bin/bash vault
/bin/vault: cannot execute binary file
$ su -s /bin/bash vault
Password: (and I have no password or I don't know it)
```

So that's why I'm using the full `sudo su -s /bin/bash vault` command.

Comment: Couple things, fyi. `su` is an older command that does the same job as `sudo` but slightly different. There is (should be) no benefit to running them both together. If you want a root command prompt you can do `sudo -i`. To run your above command you can simply do `sudo vault`. I suspect the actual issue is the use of `./pidfile` where `./` is a relative path meaning "current directory". Systemd runs commands in it's own environment and the "current directory" may not be what you expect. Perhaps there is a way to tell vault where you want to store the pidfile with an absolute path?

Comment: To get the same permissions you can do `sudo -u vault vault` where "-u vault" tells sudo to switch to the "vault" user to run the command instead of the root user. To get a command prompt as the user vault you can do `sudo -i -u vault`.

Comment: Where is the configured value for `pid_file` in the Vault Agent configuration?  If the configured location is within the `vault` user's home directory, then the issue is likely the `systemd` option `ProtectHome=read-only`.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong About the pidfile, I changed for a absolute path in the config. Now I have ```Error storing PID: could not open pid file: open /etc/vault.d/pidfile: read-only file system``` which is, indeed, a but more clear, but still confusing since I have no issue running manually the command as a vault user or even editing files as vault in the exact same location where the pidfile is.

Comment: I've made an edit why I'm using the full ```sudo -s /bin/bash vault``` command. Also, I've tried to ```ExecStart=bin/sudo su -s /bin/bash vault  -c "<command>"``` to have the same permissions but it did not like that : ```sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?```

Comment: @GracefulRestart the value is now ```pid_file = "/etc/vault.d/pidfile``` and the /home/vault, that I had to create myself (```mkhomedir_helper``` into ```chown vault:vault```) because the default vault installation did not provide it, is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option [`ProtectSystem=full` literally mounts `/etc` as read-only for the process defined in the service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ProtectSystem=):

> Takes a boolean argument or the special values "full" or "strict". If true, mounts the /usr/ and the boot loader directories (/boot and /efi) read-only for processes invoked by this unit. If set to "full", the /etc/ directory is mounted read-only, too.

You should either move the pidfile to a writable location for that process, or remove the option `ProtectSystem=full` from the service file.

You should look into all of the other `systemd` service options that you are using which you are unsure of what they do.  There are a number of other restrictions in there that may cause problems with your setup.

Comment: That was that, you are right. I deleted the ```ProtectSystem=full```line from the service config and now it works, it can write the pid into /etc/vault.d/pidfile.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `vault` is a script which launches a process, forks, saves the main PID to `./pidfile` and exits.

First, this is an old-fashioned forking script.  Therefore you need `Type=forking` in your service.  When the initial `vault` process ends, systemd will know that it should follow another process instead of detecting a stopped or failed service.

But you don't get that far, so that's not your immediate issue.

The immediate problem is this program seems to write to `./pidfile`. I doubt it's trying to write to `/etc/vault.d/pidfile` because:

1. `/etc` is almost always read-only
2. A PIDFile isn't really a configuration. It's a state, belonging in `/run` or `/var`.

Therefore we have to consider where it's really looking and really trying to create a file.  Your error message says `./pidfile`.  By default, the working directory for systemd system services is `/`.  Therefore `./pidfile` resolves to `/pidfile`.  You don't (and shouldn't) have write permission there.

Use `WorkingDirectory=%t` to set the working directory to `/run` (or maybe `WorkingDirectory=%T` for your private `/tmp`).  Your service should have write permissions there.

Finally, Consider offering `systemd` a hint for tracking the main pid with `PIDFile=%t/pidfile` (or `PIDFile=%T/pidfile`).

---

I suspect `/bin/vault` is a script which sets some environment variables, runs your program, sets up logging, forks, and saves the pidfile like this:

```
IMPORTANT_VAR="important value"
/usr/lib/vault $@ | rotatelog /var/log/vault.log &
echo $! > ./pidfile
```

We really don't need forking processes anymore.  All of that work can be delegated to systemd in a more standard way.   A near equivalent would be to take advantage of the default `Type=simple` and call the process directly.

```
[Service]
Environment=IMPORTANT_VAR="important value"
ExecStart=/usr/lib/vault agent -non-interactive -config=/etc/vault.d/agent-config-prod.hcl
```